# Linux does not support uppercase file name, any idea?

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I uploaded my website to Linux server, Linux just know the lowercase files.
for solving that I am converting all of my file name to lowercase and convert all of codes to lowercase with a website that convert to lowercase text.

for example one of my code is this:

```
 $SQL="select * from `article` WHERE `page` REGEXP '^$page' AND `first_parent_page` = $parent_page AND `level` = $level ORDER BY `page` DESC ";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL,$con);
    if($result){
        header('location:../LOGIN.php');
    }
```

This is the converted code:

```
 $sql="select * from `article` where `page` regexp '^$page' and `first_parent_page` = $parent_page and `level` = $level order by `page` desc ";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if($result){
    header('location:../login.php');
}
```

I should lowercase all codes because Linux don't know uppercase named files like **LOGIN.php**

I used this website to convert my codes [convertor](http://convertcase.net/), but this convertor convert everything to lowercase. and I don't want to convert all stuff to lowercase.

This is my question that please introduce me a way to solve my problem or please tell me does mysql work if I use it's order in lowercase like

```
SELECT * FROM 'table'
```

**USE:**

```
select * from 'table'
```

and why when I want to open a file on server with browser it says 404 Not Found.

Comment: linux has case-sensitive file system, buy mysql is case-insensitive (only table names can be case-sensitive with separate setting)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Linux of course understands uppercase files, but unlinke windows, "login.php" != "LOGIN.php". You don't have to rewrite everything to lowercase, that's crazy

Comment: but I have some files in upercase and when I want to open it the system say Not Found!. for example my file name is Logo.png when I write www.example.com/pic/Logo.png alert me that Not Found 404. and when I change name of file to logo.png everything will be OK

Comment: @Lashane do you mean: can I use select instead of SELECT (my English is not good)

Comment: Yes, the only thing case sensitive in sql statements are table names (on linux) the answer explains it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linix *does* know uppercase, but in Linux files are case sensitive.

the following files can all happily sit in the same folder:

```
LOGIN.php
Login.php
login.php
```

And each will be treated perfectly well as a different file. When converting your code, you simply need to ensure that the file you are specifying is the ACTUAL file you want to specify.

This is also applied to database structure as [described in detail here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive.

Comment: just note: SQL language is case-insensitive, but table names in mysql - filesystem dependent